# Flash Video (SWF) - how to set length/duration

Tags: flash, video, actionscript

I have several flash videos that I would like to play in a playlist in Windows Media Player.

I can add the videos without issue and play them; however, they never end.  The video completes, but there is no duration associated with the SWF file, so the playlist never moves to the next video.

I have access to Adobe Flash Professional CC and was wondering if I could use that to somehow set the duration of the video or at least add a final frame which will in turn set the duration.

Comment: In Flash CC there should be option to **export** as video (in format `avi`, `mov` or `flv`, can't remember). SWF format is just a container for code/media/application etc. Use a real video format if you want duration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash videos have their own format and that is *.FLV.

SWF files can embed FLVs, although that doesn't mean they become the FLV itself. The SWF can have a frame rate of it's own and that might not be the same with the embedded FLV, and that might influence the duration of the SWF (make it higher or lower).

The resulting SWF file can be set to loop the video(s), for example, so that can be a reason for your experience. In order to modify that and have your SWF end once the video inside ended playing you can edit the FLA file that was compiled in the SWF you're watching.

Without having access to the FLAs the only other option is to decompile the SWF and grab the FLV(s) inside (although that might not be possible - it depends on the way the SWF was compiled).